# using node-rsa to create a RSA private key

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, rsa, private-key

I am looking to create a RSA private key instance from module [NodeRSA](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa)

I am doing this:

```
var privateKey = new NodeRSA('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- <my private key> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----', 'pkcs1-private-pem');
```

But getting error :

> InvalidAsn1Error: encoding too long
>   node_modules/node-rsa/node_modules/node-rsa/node_modules/asn1/lib/ber/errors.js:7:13
>   node_modules/node-rsa/node_modules/asn1/lib/ber/reader.js:102:13
>   node_modules/node-rsa/src/formats/pkcs1.js:63:16

I have generated the private key from 'ssh-keygen' and `<my private key>` is the part of content from 5th line (taking 1 as starting) to 2nd last line.

Can any one help me to get rid of this error or at least point out my mistake.

Comment: SSH uses a different format for keys than OpenSSL / PEM, you need to export such a key to the right format before you can use them. That involves a bit more work than just copying the base 64...

Comment: Can you please reply, what extra work i should do.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=export+openssh+private+key+openssl